# jquery post to retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.post("test.jsp", {id : name}, function(data) {
});
```

Is it possible to get db values without passing any data in jQuery post? I have a query in separate page("test.jsp") which get values from DB. Is there anyway to get values without any post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `post` if the data is available in your database. You just need to `get` it and display to users in that case.